Anaconda - Cannot create env from yml file
I am running the command conda env create -f virtual_platform_mac.yml and getting these errors ...
this yml file is from a UDEMY course, so I don't understand why it shouldn't work.
Channels:

menpo
conda-forge
soumith
anaconda-fusion
defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

zlib==1.2.11=h60db283_1
zict==0.1.2=py35h74bcf12_0
zeromq==4.2.2=h131e0f7_1
yaml==0.1.7=hff548bb_1
xz==5.2.3=ha24016e_1
xlwt==1.2.0=py35hf70d7fa_0
xlwings==0.11.4=py35h12d966e_0
xlsxwriter==0.9.8=py35h4f28fc6_0
xlrd==1.1.0=py35h892fcf7_1
x264==20131217=3
wrapt==1.10.11=py35ha18cf31_0
widgetsnbextension==3.0.2=py35hdbe965d_1
wheel==0.29.0=py35ha7aa5c4_1
werkzeug==0.12.2=py35h65e0cfe_0
webencodings==0.5.1=py35hcf8ebf9_1
wcwidth==0.1.7=py35hdd0c235_0
urllib3==1.22=py35he002d57_0
unixodbc==2.3.4=h4cb4dde_1
unicodecsv==0.14.1=py35h2154ad0_0
typing==3.6.2=py35ha402c5e_0
traitlets==4.3.2=py35hd3d1486_0
tornado==4.5.2=py35h4099233_0
torchvision==0.1.9=py35_1
toolz==0.8.2=py35h9767fb5_0
tk==8.6.7=hcdce994_1
testpath==0.3.1=py35hf8009f4_0
terminado==0.6=py35hf269ddc_0
tblib==1.3.2=py35h1b9c5fd_0
tbb==4.3_20141023=0
sympy==1.1.1=py35he478fab_0
statsmodels==0.8.0=py35ha7c9052_0
sqlite==3.20.1=h900c3b0_1
sqlalchemy==1.1.13=py35h499c78e_0
spyder==3.2.3=py35h409862a_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.0.1=py35hcb4ca16_1
sphinxcontrib==1.0=py35h3eabf46_1
sphinx==1.6.3=py35ha195767_0
sortedcontainers==1.5.7=py35h53913a2_0
sortedcollections==0.5.3=py35hefac527_0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1=py35hbb7be01_0
six==1.10.0=py35h85ff2ce_1
sip==4.18.1=py35h79e1f92_2
singledispatch==3.4.0.3=py35h0acf360_0
simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35h0a3d746_0
setuptools==36.5.0=py35h52cde6a_0
seaborn==0.8.0=py35h997229a_0
scipy==0.19.1=py35hf362045_3
scikit-learn==0.19.0=py35hd036984_2
scikit-image==0.13.0=py35hf7e7ad6_1
ruamel_yaml==0.11.14=py35h61782da_2
rope==0.10.5=py35h5d4ce6c_0
requests==2.18.4=py35h0d65e6b_1
readline==7.0=h81b24a6_3
qtpy==1.3.1=py35h743f03e_0
qtconsole==4.3.1=py35hd6d667b_0
qtawesome==0.4.4=py35h21e61ad_0
qt==5.6.2=h9975529_14
pyzmq==16.0.2=py35h1c7c2ed_2
pyyaml==3.12=py35hf8cec8a_1
pywavelets==0.5.2=py35h9dc8fb8_0
pytz==2017.2=py35h9789cde_1
pytorch==0.2.0=py35_4cu75
python.app==2=py35hfd15c6f_5
python-dateutil==2.6.1=py35h10515e0_1
python==3.5.4=he1de2d4_12
pytest==3.2.1=py35hff7db55_1
pytables==3.4.2=np113py35_0
pysocks==1.6.7=py35h3cfcbe1_1
pyqt==5.6.0=py35hbd126f6_6
pyparsing==2.2.0=py35h31fab04_0
pyopenssl==17.2.0=py35h4737193_0
pyodbc==4.0.17=py35h472b9e3_0
pylint==1.7.2=py35h9a30617_0
pygments==2.2.0=py35h392a662_0
pyflakes==1.5.0=py35h8c85a20_1
pycurl==7.43.0=py35h69e9701_3
pycrypto==2.6.1=py35h9b8452d_1
pycparser==2.18=py35hab820b0_1
pycosat==0.6.2=py35h02519d1_0
pycodestyle==2.3.1=py35he0976b1_0
py==1.4.34=py35hcbeeded_1
ptyprocess==0.5.2=py35hfc37984_0
psutil==5.2.2=py35h999cee3_0
prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py35h93950c5_0
ply==3.10=py35hd0aaff5_0
pkginfo==1.4.1=py35h568fed1_0
pip==9.0.1=py35hd4ef823_2
pillow==4.2.1=py35h0180db1_0
pickleshare==0.7.4=py35h9517181_0
pexpect==4.2.1=py35hde8bc66_0
pep8==1.7.0=py35h079c796_0
pcre==8.41=h29eefc5_0
patsy==0.4.1=py35ha57ee9e_0
pathlib2==2.3.0=py35hba2ddec_0
path.py==10.3.1=py35hd680d3f_0
partd==0.3.8=py35h6fadee7_0
pandocfilters==1.4.2=py35hff87490_1
pandoc==1.19.2.1=ha5e8f32_1
pandas==0.20.3=py35h5e2f206_2
packaging==16.8=py35h2e4dc9b_0
openssl==1.0.2l=h57f3a61_2
openpyxl==2.4.8=py35h6e1d452_1
opencv3==3.1.0=py35_0
olefile==0.44=py35h1f523c6_0
odo==0.5.1=py35h7f7a387_0
numpydoc==0.7.0=py35h296b98c_0
numpy==1.13.1=py35he58e7f4_2
numexpr==2.6.2=py35h0d5eb93_1
numba==0.35.0=np113py35_6
notebook==5.0.0=py35he0030f0_2
nose==1.3.7=py35h9ce1e3a_2
nltk==3.2.4=py35hf54be8e_0
networkx==1.11=py35hd138405_0
ncurses==6.0=ha932d30_1
nbformat==4.4.0=py35h41c2038_0
nbconvert==5.3.1=py35h63fb950_0
navigator-updater==0.1.0=py35hd04e0bf_0
multipledispatch==0.4.9=py35h2fbb584_0
msgpack-python==0.4.8=py35h2751e37_0
mpmath==0.19=py35h359e7d7_2
mpfr==3.1.5=h7fa3772_1
mpc==1.0.3=hc455b36_4
mkl-service==1.1.2=py35h6a6947a_4
mkl==2018.0.0=hc285769_4
mistune==0.7.4=py35h0ccc54f_0
mccabe==0.6.1=py35h3f6a9a1_0
matplotlib==2.0.2=py35ha43f773_1
markupsafe==1.0=py35h9ba0a7f_1
lxml==3.8.0=py35h3ba66aa_0
locket==0.2.0=py35h58cf053_1
llvmlite==0.20.0=py35_0
libxslt==1.1.29=h95a2935_5
libxml2==2.9.4=hbd0960b_5
libtiff==4.0.8=h8cd0352_9
libssh2==1.8.0=h1218725_2
libsodium==1.0.13=hba5e272_2
libpng==1.6.32=hce72d48_2
libiconv==1.15=h99df5da_5
libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
libffi==3.2.1=hd939716_3
libedit==3.1=hb4e282d_0
libcxxabi==4.0.1=hebd6815_0
libcxx==4.0.1=h579ed51_0
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1=py35h7293e74_0
jupyterlab_launcher==0.4.0=py35h3e578e6_0
jupyterlab==0.27.0=py35h269f579_2
jupyter_core==4.3.0=py35h1d2ac15_0
jupyter_console==5.2.0=py35hd2aa692_1
jupyter_client==5.1.0=py35hfe06ecd_0
jupyter==1.0.0=py35hf3a1ed8_0
jsonschema==2.6.0=py35h2dd9e4b_0
jpeg==9b=haccd157_1
jinja2==2.9.6=py35h7194686_1
jedi==0.10.2=py35heb0647e_0
jdcal==1.3=py35h9028778_0
jbig==2.1=h4d881f8_0
itsdangerous==0.24=py35hfbd69cd_1
isort==4.2.15=py35h0db285e_0
ipywidgets==7.0.0=py35hb70205d_0
ipython_genutils==0.2.0=py35hf129286_0
ipython==6.1.0=py35h3f7db8a_1
ipykernel==4.6.1=py35h9865fc8_0
intel-openmp==2018.0.0=hdd0ccc9_7
imagesize==0.7.1=py35h1ad78fc_0
imageio==2.2.0=py35_0
idna==2.6=py35h01aacb0_1
icu==58.2=hea21ae5_0
html5lib==0.999999999=py35ha3ce4a6_0
heapdict==1.0.0=py35h86051b3_0
hdf5==1.8.17=2
h5py==2.7.0=np113py35_0
greenlet==0.4.12=py35h49b4c26_0
gmpy2==2.0.8=py35he9f684a_1
gmp==6.1.2=h4a9834d_0
glob2==0.5=py35h6ff56de_0
glib==2.53.6=ha08cb78_1
gevent==1.2.2=py35h8412070_0
gettext==0.19.8.1=hb0f4f8b_2
get_terminal_size==1.0.0=h7520d66_0
freetype==2.8=h143eb01_0
flask-cors==3.0.3=py35h7e589ad_0
flask==0.12.2=py35h7284a24_0
filelock==2.0.12=py35h3e43021_0
ffmpeg==3.2.4=1
fastcache==1.0.2=py35h8aa0158_0
expat==2.2.4=h8f26bf8_1
et_xmlfile==1.0.1=py35h40eb147_0
entrypoints==0.2.3=py35h837ec6f_2
docutils==0.14=py35hb13dbd9_0
distributed==1.18.3=py35hdc3e6de_0
decorator==4.1.2=py35hf37c5b3_0
dbus==1.10.22=h50d9ad6_0
datashape==0.5.4=py35hd065018_0
dask-core==0.15.2=py35hb25e3a2_0
dask==0.15.2=py35h4901172_0
cytoolz==0.8.2=py35h232c442_0
cython==0.26.1=py35h55fee34_0
cycler==0.10.0=py35hb89929e_0
curl==7.55.1=h7601780_3
cryptography==2.0.3=py35hde935b2_1
contextlib2==0.5.5=py35hc2c67b4_0
colorama==0.3.9=py35h1d66b2b_0
clyent==1.2.2=py35h63ae3d7_0
cloudpickle==0.4.0=py35ha0eea39_0
click==6.7=py35hcc65ea6_0
chardet==3.0.4=py35h16a84c2_1
cffi==1.10.0=py35hca2225f_1
certifi==2017.7.27.1=py35h0fdde5e_0
ca-certificates==2017.08.26=ha1e5d58_0
bzip2==1.0.6=1
bottleneck==1.2.1=py35h969083f_0
boto==2.48.0=py35h10f7326_1
bokeh==0.12.7=py35hcfea997_1
bleach==2.0.0=py35h7b4af82_0
blaze==0.11.3=py35h385aa17_0
bkcharts==0.2=py35h18a45e2_0
bitarray==0.8.1=py35hbb560e9_0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0=py35hb75f182_1
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size==1.0.0=py35h40fcb1f_2
backports==1.0=py35h2556c16_1
babel==2.5.0=py35h6f05a75_0
astropy==2.0.2=py35haa6f39b_4
astroid==1.5.3=py35hc14dc17_0
asn1crypto==0.22.0=py35ha010153_1
appscript==1.0.1=py35hdfff33c_1
appnope==0.1.0=py35hd172556_0
anaconda-project==0.8.0=py35h19d87e7_0
anaconda-navigator==1.6.8=py35h9418ac0_1
anaconda-client==1.6.5=py35hf878a34_0
anaconda==custom=py35_0

Current channels:

https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/osx-arm64
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
https://conda.anaconda.org/soumith/osx-arm64
https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/osx-arm64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64

ALSO THIS - SAME ERROR

import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/init.py", line 181, in 
bootstrap()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/init.py", line 175, in bootstrap
if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/init.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/typing/init.py", line 168, in 
LayerId = cv2.dnn.DictValue
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'DictValue'
conda update --all
pip install opencv-python
added conda-forge
anaconda login
reinstall cv2
pip install opencv-python-headless

fixed:
downgrade openCV:
pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64 for M1 silicon
the libraries weren't necessary for startup. but ran into another error while trying to run the script they provided in spyder IDE. error: opencv: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting...
the fix for this was to create your python environment and just run it through terminal. it will ask for permission to access camera and the facial recognition worked

this yml file is from a UDEMY course, so I don't understand why it shouldn't work
This is unfortunately no guarantee that it will work out of the box. From what I can tell (I don't know Udemy, but briefly checked their website), anyone can create a course there. Here are some of the issues with this env file:

The versions specified in the yml file are ancient, for example pip is supposed to be version 9, released 2018, all is specified to be python 3.5 which reached end of life in 2015
Whoever created it had no idea of conda best practices. For one, the env is way to crowded to be of much use. It contains all of anaconda plus extra packages which make it a mess to be solvable. They should have created an env for the course with only the specific packages and then exported with conda env export --from-history.

For you specifically, more problems arise:
You seem to have an apple silicone CPU (arm64) which was only released in 2020, while, as mentioned above, the package versions required here predate your CPU, so there is no way you can install them natively. You might be able to if you create a x64 environment and remove the =py35h18a45e2_0 parts of the requirements, but even then I would assume that most package versions are no longer available from conda channels.
From the package list it looks to me like it is supposed to be an image processing/machine learning type of course. Since the course seems to be
a) outdated
b) poorly maintained
I highly recommend that you simply try to find another course that covers similar topics, but is more up to date and maintained, which will greatly improve your learning and usability of the skills/tehcniques you will be taught.
